# nth preceding element in XPATH (sibling or ancestor )

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Say my markup is :

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
 <div>blbaba</div>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>b</p>
 <p>c</p>
 <p>d</p>
 <div id="a1">blbaba</div>
 <p>e</p>
 <p>f</p>
 <p>g</p>
 <p>h</p> 
 <div>blbaba</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I select an element relative to a particular element , that is exactly `n` nodes before (in the document can be parent or sibling that is before ) .

Example:

I want to select the 2nd `<p>` element before the div with `@id ="a1"`, so my expected element is `<p>c</p>`

Answer (score 4):

The `preceding::` and `ancestor::` axes **are non-intersecting**, therefore in the general case you will not be able to select the wanted element, unless you use the elements selected by both these axes.

To quote the **[W3C XPath 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)**:

> •the preceding axis contains all nodes in the same document as the
>   context node that are before the context node in document order,
>   **excluding any ancestors** and excluding attribute nodes and namespace
>   nodes

**Use**:

```
(//p[@id='a1']/ancestor::div | //p[@id='a1']/preceding::div) 
                                                        [last() -$n +1]
```

This selects the $n-th `div` element (backwards in document order) belonging to the union of the preceding and ancestor `div` elements of the `p` element whose `id` attribute's value is the string "`a1`". Here we assume that the `id` attribute identifies uniquely the element to which it belongs.

**For example, if we have this XML document** (I made the example more realistic, because `div`s can be nested, while `p`s cannot):

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div>
          <p>a</p>
          <p>b</p>
          <p>c</p>
          <div id="y">
             <p>d</p>
             <div>blbaba</div>
             <p id="a1">e</p>
             <p>f</p>
             <p>g</p>
             <p>h</p>
             <div>blbaba</div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And we want to get the 2nd `div` before (in document order) the `p` with `id` "`a1`",** then this XPath expression selects the wanted `div` element:

```
(//p[@id='a1']/ancestor::div | //p[@id='a1']/preceding::div)
                                                        [last() -1]
```

**And this short XSLT transformation proves that the XPath expression above selects exactly the wanted `div` element** (by evaluating the XPath expression and copying the whole selected `div` element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "(//p[@id='a1']/ancestor::div | //p[@id='a1']/preceding::div)
                                                        [last() -1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on the above source XML document, it selects the wanted `div` element and copies it to the output**:

```
<div id="y">
   <p>d</p>
   <div>blbaba</div>
   <p id="a1">e</p>
   <p>f</p>
   <p>g</p>
   <p>h</p>
   <div>blbaba</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combing both doesn't work in Chrome (for instance), you can check first if it has sibling, if it is null then get the ancestor by a second XPath.

An explanation of this behavior of `or` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13051768/184201).

```html
<html><head><script>
function doTest() {
    testElement('a1');
    testElement('a2');
  }

  function testElement(id) {
      var ancestor = getPath("//div[@id='" + id +"']/ancestor::*[2]");
      alert('ancestor ' + ancestor);

      var sibling = getPath("//div[@id='" + id + "']/preceding-sibling::*[2]");
      alert('sibling ' + sibling);

      var both = getPath("//div[@id='" + id + "']/preceding-sibling::*[2]|//div[@id='" + id +"']/ancestor::*[2]");
      alert('both ' + both);
  }

  function getPath(path) {
      return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  }
  </script></head>
<body onload='doTest()'>
<div>
 <div id='a1'>blbaba</div>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>b</p>
 <p id='me'>c</p>
 <p>d</p>
 <div id="a2">blbaba</div>
 <p>e</p>
 <p>f</p>
 <p>g</p>
 <p>h</p> 
 <div>blbaba</div>
</div>
</body>
```